# how to enable logging for ManagementClass Install method

Tags: c#, wmi, windows-installer

I'm using the below code to install the MSI in remote machine. Installation is succeeded, but i want to generate log file for installation steps. please help me on enabling logging.

```
ManagementClass productClass = new ManagementClass(this.m_WorkingNamespace, new ManagementPath("Win32_Product"), new ObjectGetOptions());

try
{
    object[] parameters = { msiFilePath, installOptions, allUsers };
    UInt32 returnValue = (UInt32)productClass.InvokeMethod("Install", parameters);
    if (returnValue > 0)
        throw new Exception("Installation failed. error  code = " + returnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal msi call looks like something like this:

```
msiexec /i "yourmsi.msi" /l*v "C:\log\example.log"
```

as you can see you can add a custom log path with you callup of you msi. Make sure the folder for the log is existing and the msi can access it during installation.

Explanation of paramenters

- /l - create a protokoll
- * - Log all information, except for v and x options
- v -  Verbose output

If you need futher information for msiexec command lines you can run `msiexec` from your command line and a help window is shown.